# How to setup Apache Proxy for secure websocket WSS for an apolloserver app in production environment?

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl-certificate, apollo-server

I have been testing different answers, but nothing works.

I have a NodeJS app with ApolloServer for GraphQL, and it is configured with SSL certificated, and in my developer environment the subscription is working.

This is part of the APP.

```
  const app = express();
  const server = new ApolloServer(...*more code here*...)
  const keys_dir = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/';
  const server_options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(keys_dir + 'privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(keys_dir + 'cert.pem'),
  };
  httpServer = https.createServer(server_options, app);
  server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer);
```

However, when I move it to my production server that runs Apache (2.4.41) running on Ubuntu 20.04, I cannot make secure web-socket work correctly. I am testing the socket connection with https://www.websocket.org/echo.html, and with the react application, that is also working on my developer environment.

this is my Apache configuration after several search on google and Stackoverflow:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName test.com
        ServerAlias www.test.com
        ServerAdmin admin@test.com

         DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/chain.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All

                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ProxyRequests off
        SSLProxyEngine on

        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

        <Location /api>
                ProxyPass https://127.0.0.1:4000/graphql
                ProxyPassReverse https://127.0.0.1:4000/graphql

                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        # This is for websocket requests
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia on
        <Location /wss>
                ProxyPass  wss://127.0.0.1:4000/graphql
                ProxyPassReverse wss://127.0.0.1:4000/graphql

                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
                RewriteRule (.*) wss://127.0.0.1:4000/graphql [P]
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas about how properly setup the Apache proxy?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: try out this link https://amartya.in/setting-up-secure-websockets/

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @DilukAngelo I didn't found nothing good... I try different solutions but no good one. At the end I switch from Apache to nginx directly to my docker container running node server. I used this https://nginxproxymanager.com/